How to stream a video that has the moov atom at the end of the video
I currently have an HTTP pseudo streaming service, where you can serve files from to a client. Some files can be video files which are streamed using HTML  tag. Now for the files that have the moov atom at the end of the file, they cannot be streamed within Chrome, however they stream just fine using Firefox. I have created a client functionality where you download the file completely before streaming, but that is not efficient as per huge video files, it would take a really long time to do so. I've seen there is a way to use range requests to overcome this issue, but I don't really understand how it works..
I've seen the post right here: Sample http range request session
But I don't really understand how it works
Can somebody explain to me the flow, or what to do in order to make video stream smooth in Chrome ?

you can reencode those mp4 with the moov at the end and put it at the start

@PerdiEstaquel this is not an option, as I said my server handles multiple types of files, so it would be a really cumbersome process to do that.
